# How to run script file(.sh file) inside Dockerfile?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I am creating a Docker image.
I have 'install.sh' script file and want to run this script file in Dockerfile.

How should i do this ?

Comment: What do you mean "execute *in* Dockerfile": you want to run it inside the docker container, or while creating the image?

Answer (score 17):

Steps as follows :

1. Copy '.sh' file to container

   ```
   COPY install.sh .
   ```
2. Executing '.sh' file

   ```
   RUN ./install.sh
   ```

'install.sh' file should be in current working directory else you can specify path.

Answer (score 5):

Inside `Dockerfile`, just add call to your script using `RUN` command as:

```
RUN /path/to/install.sh
```